# Ошибка: /usr/bin/sh: cc: command not found ( Это установка Redis )

Tags: windows, redis

Хотел установить Redis на Windows 10 делал всё как написано на официальном сайте.

Installation
Download, extract and compile Redis with:

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.3.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.3.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.3
$ make
```

После `make` была ошибка `C:\Program no such directory or file`

Потом ввел команду которую вводила команда `make` но изменил что бы не было ошибки на это

```
cd "src" && "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/make" all
```

После этого я появилась ошибка `/usr/bin/sh: cc: command not found`

Повторяю: Я устанавливал Redis на Windows 10 с официального сайта https://redis.io/download

Comment: Эм, я не смотрел `Makefile` но почему-то мне кажется, что он написан для linux. Вроде как под windows портируют redis тут: https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis

Comment: @nobody там и собранные установщики в релизах есть. Только репозиторий всё равно протухший

Comment: @nobody если бы всё было так просто( Он там очень старый, так бы я уже давно сам установил.

Comment: @DarkRou но всегда же есть вариант с `docker`, разве нет? :) По Вашей ссылке там даже образ вроде как можно скачать...

Comment: @nobody к сожалению не работал с докером, да и я привык делать всё непосредственно со своего устройства без разных "Помогаторов" Я бы мог просто скачать `Homestead` от `Laravel` в нем `Redis` вроде идёт "с завода" :)  А может есть способ установить эту команду `cc` ? потому что сначала была та же проблема с `make` но нашел где его скачать. Но с этим `cc` ответов не нашел

Comment: Не хочу Вас огорчать, но судя по https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/blob/3.0/README.md#windows-specific-changes одним `cc` дело не кончится...

Comment: Может лучше всё-таки в виртуалке с линуксом подобную штуку повторить? Не уверен, что даже в WSL это проканает.

Comment: А, тут знакомый кинул ссылку: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/ . На ВСЛ проканает.

Comment: @donRumata спасибо пробовал разобраться так как я делал тогда, но в конце концов использовал wsl и всё сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо don Rumata

> А, тут знакомый кинул ссылку: [redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10](http://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10) . На ВСЛ проканает

Использовал WSL на дистрибутиве Ubuntu. Сделал как написано в том гайде и всё запустилось